# Disable output compression from Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, compression, gzip

I'm developing a web app using Symfony and I have a heavy process in one action, using a KernelEvents::TERMINATE listener. The problem is that request does not end until the heavy process ends. Can I avoid gzip compression for this action directly from code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add listener and services.yml

Comment: class StuffSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $container;
    private $router;
    
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, Router $a_router)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->router = $a_router;
    }
    
    public function onTerminate(PostResponseEvent $event)
    {
       doStuff();
    }
    
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(KernelEvents::TERMINATE => 'onTerminate',
        );
    }
}

Comment: StuffSubscriber:
            class: AppBundle\EventSubscriber\StuffSubscriber
            arguments: ['@service_container', '@router']
            tags:
                - {name: kernel.event_subscriber, synthetic: true, connection: default}